# ggplot2 - remove part of legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the second part of the legend but maintain the colours in the plot. My code is below (any help greatly appreciated):

```
nmds.gplot<-ggplot(nmds2,aes(x=nmds1,y=nmds2))
nmds.gplot + aes(shape=factor(yr)) +
      geom_point (aes(colour=factor(Trt)),size=4) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
      scale_x_continuous(name="NMDS Axis 1") +
      scale_y_continuous(name="NMDS Axis 2") +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=16)) +
      theme (axis.title.y=element_text(size=16)) +
      theme (axis.text.y  = element_text(size=14)) +
      theme (axis.text.x  = element_text(size=14)) +
      geom_vline (xintercept=0, linetype = "dotted") +
      geom_hline (xintercept=0, linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you bother to google "ggplot remove legend"?

Comment: well it's not simply remove legend - but remove part of the legend; if you marked it as duplicate it would have been helpful to actually link to where it has been addressed.

Comment: Hi Anand, could you explain why the question linked by Henrik does not work for you. `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, shape=factor(cyl))) + 
      geom_point (aes(colour=factor(gear))) +
  guides(colour=FALSE)` would seem to do what you want. If not can you please update your question with a reproducible example. Thanks